# Source From Standard In (Bash on OSX)

Tags: bash, macos

I am trying to do something like this

```
 ruby test.rb | source /dev/stdin
```

where test.rb just prints out `cd /`. There are no errors, but it doesn't do anything either. If I use this:

```
 ruby test.rb > /tmp/eraseme2352; source /tmp/eraseme2352
```

it works fine, but I want to avoid the intermediate file.

**Edit:** The whole point of this is that the changes need to persist when the command is done. Sorry I didn't make that clearer earlier.

Comment: Your first command 'works'; the trouble is that the pipeline runs in a sub-shell, so the sub-shell sources the output from ruby, and then exits, leaving the parent process unchanged.  That is why the explicit temporary file works as you want.  Look up 'Process Substitution' (§3.5.6 in the 4.0 Bash Manual) and see whether you can use: `source <(ruby test.rb)`.

Comment: Empirically, it doesn't work: that also runs in a sub-shell, I guess.

Comment: Doesn't work - because you get `sh: syntax error near unexpected token '('`?  That's what I got on Snow Leopard with 'sh' as my shell.  But it runs OK if I'm using bash instead of sh.  If I try `cat <(echo a b c)` I get the result I expect (one line of output with 'a b c').  If I try 'source' or '.' instead, it seems to be ignored - which I take to be equivalent to "it forks and execs the command and the sub-shell does the source and then exits".  Worth a try, but not the answer.  It does look like you will have to do the job the long-hand way, remembering to erase the eraseme file ASAP.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan for your patience and help with this one.

Comment: @Jonathan: try `source <(echo 'echo a b c')` or `source <(echo 'testvar=TestVal'); echo $testvar`

Comment: @Dennis: I did - and to my considerable surprise, it didn't seem to work.  I'm on MacOS X 10.6.3 with bash 3.2.48, FWIW (where the .48 might be Apple badging of the version number).  I just retried with your example; I also tried with 'set -x' in effect.  It didn't seem to be doing anything reasonable.  Hmmm...and in Bash 4.1 (which I just compiled - having downloaded it earlier today), it works as you'd expect.  So, there seems to be a bug fix between Bash 3.2.48 supplied by Apple and Bash 4.1 as available from GNU.

Comment: @Jonathan: I just tested it in Bash 3.2.49(23)-release under CygWin and it doesn't work. It does, however, in 4.0.33(1)-release in Ubuntu so you're probably correct about the bug fix, but I didn't find a reference to it at http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/NEWS

Comment: "/eraseme" - Surely you don't write temporary files in the root directory?

Comment: @Dennis Williamson, when I'm testing stuff, sometimes I do. That way I'm sure to find them later :)

Comment: @Dennis Williamson, fixing the question now, good point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try:

```
$(ruby test.rb)
```

`$(...)` tells bash to execute whatever output is produced by command inside `()`.

Comment: While we're here: is there any way to get the shell to NOT show the commands as they're being run?

Comment: Beware that this only works if the Ruby script outputs just a single command line. If it spits out multiple lines, they will all be joined together into one big command.

Comment: @Thomas, oh, didn't think of that. I'll unmark this as best answer for now hoping to get a better best answer.

Comment: @Thomas, actually that's not true. Not sure why, but in trying it with multiple lines it works perfectly.

Comment: @yar: If it works for you, great. But `$(echo -e 'ls\ncd')` gives me `ls: cannot access cd: No such file or directory`. A quick scan through the bash manpage shows that it might have to do with the value of `IFS`.

Comment: @Thomas, not sure what's going on. Your test failed for me too, yet this `tell app "Terminal" to do script "$(paste_env)" ` works and the results is many lines of code. Something tricky here, not sure.

Answer (score 3):

```
eval `ruby test.rb`
```

Comment: Why would you need the `eval`?

Comment: @Thomas: because, for example, `eval $(echo 'var1=27;var2=38')` works as expected sets those variables in the current shell. Without the `eval`, it's executed as one command and gives an error: "var1=27;var2=38: command not found".

Comment: @Dennis Williamson: are the backticks equivalent to the `$()`? Then I should mark this one as best answer, seems?

Comment: @yar: They are mostly equivalent, but `$()` is [preferred](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082).

Answer (score 3):

The following code works for me on Mac OS X 10.6.7:

```
/bin/bash

sw_vers   # Mac OS X 10.6.7

bash --version   # GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin10.0)

source /dev/stdin <<<'echo a b c'

source /dev/stdin  <<< "$(ruby -e 'puts "echo a b c"')"

source /dev/stdin <<<'testvar=TestVal'; echo $testvar


source /dev/stdin <<-'EOF'
echo a b c
EOF

source /dev/stdin <<-'EOF'
$(ruby -e 'puts "echo a b c"') 
EOF

(
source /dev/stdin <<-'EOF'
testvar=TestVal
EOF
echo $testvar
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Until a more experienced bash hacker comes along to correct me, you could do this:

```
for c in `ruby test.rb` ; do $c ; done
```

**Caution**: This doesn't do what you want. Read the comments!

Comment: That could be useful, too. Thanks.

Comment: This will treat each 'word' (blank separated tokens) in the output of the Ruby script as a command.  If no commands have arguments, it will work.  If any command has arguments, it will not work.

Comment: The problem is that this is the problem I'm trying to avoid: learning shell scripting. Is there any way for me to format my output so as to make it work for multiple lines? What I really want to do is `| source`

Comment: @Jonathan: Argh, whoops. I'd only tested with simple commands. Will leave it here with a warning.

Answer (score 1):

bash (not sh):

```
while read -a line
do
  "${line[@]}"
done < <(somescript)
```

Spaces in arguments to commands will need to be backslash-escaped in order to work.

Comment: nice, thanks, but I think I might go with `eval $()` as a best answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about just

```
ruby test.rb | bash
```

Comment: This will execute the commands in a subshell. Any side-effects like changing directories or setting environment variables will be lost.

Comment: Indeed it will. Not using a subshell wasn't exactly listed as a requirement... the $() syntax seems much nicer though.

Comment: It's kind of implied as a requirement given the example code.